# MongoDB migration ABP

Tags: .net, mongodb, migration, abp

I have installed the ABP with mongoDB and it is on my local machine but having this issue when running the .DBMigrator

[10:52:51 INF] Started database migrations...
[10:52:51 INF] Migrating schema for host database...
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.Ensure.IsNotNull[T](T value, String paramName)

"ConnectionStrings": {
"Default": "mongodb://localhost:27017/HelloWord"
},

Comment: Please share the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't change the ConnectionString in DbMigrator project's `appsettings.json`

[image]